# Some questions about html5 and css

Tags: html, css

Questions(A is wrote by myself, and B is from online course):

1. A can achieve the same effect which is more simplle than B, which should I choose when in real project?
2. I tried to delete the a11y and found that there's no influence on results, so what's a11y in B for?
3. how can .button li a:after,.button li a:after in B form a border? why don't do that like me just add a box-shadow to li or a?
   A(css&html)

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

.button li {
    float: left;
}

.button li a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 107px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #d3d2d2;
}

.button li .button-inner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.mask {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 107px;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    /* border-radius: 50px; */
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.button li a:hover .mask {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="button">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="button-inner">
                        探索
                    </span>
                    <span class="mask"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

B(css&html)

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

.button ul li {
    float: left;
}

.button li a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    /* 文字间距 */
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button-inner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 22px;
    padding: 5px 37px 0 37px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.a11y {
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 1px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    padding-top: 0px;
    line-height: 46px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
    transform: translate(0%, 105%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.button li a:after,
.button li a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    bottom: 1.1px;
    right: 1px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #d3d2d2;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.button li a:hover .mask {
    transform: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="button">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="button-inner">
                        探索
                        <span class="a11y"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mask"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give z-index to an element, it gets that index relative to the scope. So in the second block of code from online source, they gave scope of `position: absolute;` to the :before and :after pseudo elements.

You can modify your code to have position absolute too and it will give it expected z-index rendering, however then it will move the element to a different place on the screen, as it's not bounded by the parent container anymore.

Thus, a good way is to add a pseudo element and give it the styling.

However if you want to make your code work, simply change the z-index of mask from 0 to -1.

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

.button li {
    float: left;
}

.button li a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 107px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #d3d2d2;
}

.button li .button-inner {
    z-index: 3;
}

.mask {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -35px;
    width: 107px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.button li a:hover .mask {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="button">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="button-inner">
                        探索
                    </span>
                    <span class="mask"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks  for answering,I don't understand that why still need a pseudo when i have to add position. i just need to give the mask position:absolute and give it's parents position:relative, it will stay in parent container. 
By the way,I have added positive to button-inner and it worked, but there still some questions need to be answered.